# Как обновить данные в mysql при отправке запроса post?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, post

Имеется прямой post запрос вида: domain.ru/form.php?date=2016-01-15 03:00:57&name=toster , который в базу данных записывает id (A_I), время, имя.

Все работает , как надо, но появилась необходимость при точно таком же запросе, в том же самом обработчике ОБНОВИТЬ (перезаписать имя, не меняя время и id) данные. Так вот , когда я обращаюсь по той же ссылке , но поменяв имя (domain.ru/form.php?date=2016-01-15 03:00:57&name=name) , не чего не происходит, не добавляются не изменяются данные, как это можно исправить?

Код формы:

```
require 'connect.php';
$date = trim($_REQUEST['date']);
$name = trim($_REQUEST['name']);

$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO box (date, name)" .
"VALUES('{$date}', '{$name}');";
mysql_query($insert_sql);
```

Comment: а как вы понимаете, что надо добавить или обновить?

Comment: Вообще надо что то типа `on duplicate key update` но надо же еще решить какую именно запись в базе менять, т.е. нужны условия поиска старой записи ...